# Can't find the proper CSS selector

Tags: html, css, selector

In the following code I try to target the span that basically follows the checkbox in the document. So only the span that is in the same line as the checkbox is supposed to have a line-through once the checkbox is checked.
Here is my HTML code:

```css
.checkbox:checked + span{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
       <form action="#checked" class="form"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox">
       </form>
       <span>Clean the house</span>

   </li>
</ul>
```

I know that this can't work because my span doesn't directly follow the .checkbox since the .checkbox is in a form. But I have no idea how to select the following span.
Now, I have already tried to put the span inside the form. This would work then, but how can I select the span in the example above?

Comment: You can't...for the reasons you have stated. The span is not related to the checkbox.